# Add a second value to a key in python

Tags: python, list, key

I need to add second value to a key in a dictionary from another list. can someone explain how to do this?

This is what I am trying to go for but i keep getting error any ideas?

```
third_value_list =[0] 
for i in third_value_list 
num_list = [1,2] 
val_list = [0,1] 
dict1 = dict((k, [v]+i) for (k, v) in zip(num_list,val_list)) 
print dict1
```

i want to use a loop to loop through the list but i keep getting error

desired output I want is key: x,y below:

```
{1: [0,0], 2:[1,0]}
```

Comment: Use a list for the value.

Comment: The only way to do this is to use a list or a tuple for the value.  You can't have two separate values correlate to a specific key.  How would it know which one to return in a given context?  And if you need both of them, then you're going to have to return them as a list or a tuple anyway.

Comment: What is the use of port_list?

Comment: Should the desired output not look like: `{1: 0,0, 2: 1,6}`, overlooking the fact that only `{1: [0,0], 2: [1,6]}`  makes sense syntactically?

Comment: this is the desired output: {1: 0,0, 2: 1,0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this approach:

```
third_value_list =[0]
num_list = [1,2]
val_list = [0,1]
# If you want it as a tuple, then just use tuple([v]+third_value_list) below
dict1 = dict((k, [v]+third_value_list) for (k, v) in zip(num_list,val_list))
print dict1
```

This will print

`{1: [0, 0], 2: [1, 0]} # Tuple variant will print {1: (0, 0), 2: (1, 0)}`

**Note**

You can't define dictionaries like this in python:

```
>>> {1: 2,3, 2:1,0}
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1
    {1: 2,3, 2:1,0}
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Lists, tuples and other collections will work just fine:

```
>>> {1: (2,3), 2:(1,0)}
{1: (2, 3), 2: (1, 0)}
>>> {1: [2,3], 2:[1,0]}
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 0]}
```

Edit for your latest comment (see below):

```
>>> d = {1: 0}
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for k, v in d.iteritems():
...     d[k] = tuple([v]+l)
...     
>>> d
{1: (0, 1, 2, 3)}
>>>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question again, sorry the formatting is off and I can't really follow the indentation in the comment.

Comment: third_value_list =[0] 
   
for i in third_value_list 
   num_list = [1,2] 
val_list = [0,1] 
dict1 = dict((k, [v]+i) for (k, v) in zip(num_list,val_list)) 
print dict1

Comment: I see, on the phone now, but will edit when I get a chance in an hour or so. However, you don't need to loop over the third list for desired output. `[v]+third_value_list` is adding the two lists together already (if third_value_list was [0, 1], you'd get something like [0, 0, 1])

Comment: I keep getting ((1,[0,0]),(2,[1,0]))
I need {(1:(0,0)),(2,(1,0))}

Comment: Use this: `dict1=dict((k, tuple([v]+third_value_list)) for (k, v) in zip(num_list,val_list))` when you create `dict1`

Comment: if i have a dictionary already dict1={(1:1}
how would append to  dict1 to make it {1:[1,0]}